# Calculate column mean on single column in a database

Tags: r, time-series, mean

I'm trying to extract the first 50 observations from a db and then obtaining the mean for each column. I'm trying with the following code, but is not working.

```
h_1_ctrl_mean <- data_1_ctrl %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 50) %>% 
  mutate(cummean(c(1, 2, 3, 4)))
```

I'm quite naive to dplyr and I am sure there is an easier way to do it. Can someone help me there?
thanks!

Comment: base R: `mean(c(1,2,3,4))`;  `colMeans( matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 4, 4) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> extract the first 50 observations from a db

Use `slice(1:50)` for that. `slice_sample` is for random samples of rows.

> obtaining the mean for each column

Use `mean()` for mean - `cummean` is cumulative mean (mean of 1st, mean of 1st and 2nd, mean of 1st and 2nd and 3rd, etc.). And we use `mutate` to keep the same number of rows; it sounds like you want to collapse or "summarize" the data down to one row (with the mean value), so we use `summarize()`, not `mutate()`. And for "all columns" we use `across(everything(), ...)` inside that.

Putting it together:

```
your_data %>%
  slice(1:50) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), mean))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I voted this as the answer but the previous comment says the same, but in this case is beautful explained! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
h_1_ctrl_mean <- data_1_ctrl %>% 
  slice(1:50) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), mean))
```

If we use `mtcars`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), mean))
```

Gives us:

```
       mpg    cyl     disp       hp     drat      wt     qsec     vs      am   gear   carb
1 20.09062 6.1875 230.7219 146.6875 3.596563 3.21725 17.84875 0.4375 0.40625 3.6875 2.8125
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `summarise_all` and `slice` from `dplyr` package.

```
data_1_ctrl %>%
   slice(1:50) %>%
   summarise_all(mean)
```

Comment: `summarise_all` is superseded